# not able to click the button in protractor with non-angular site

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to click the login button after sending the keys.

I am able to fill email and password fields but for some reason it will not click the login button.

here is the mark up

```
<section id="loginBox">
                <h4 class="ban">Log in to your account</h4>
                <p>
                    <label for="inputEmailHandle">Email / Handle:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmailHandle" name="inputEmailHandle" value="">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
                    <input id="inputPassword" type="password" name="inputPassword" autocomplete="off">
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
                    <a href="/reset">forgot password?</a>
                </p>
            </section>
```

I have tried several things.

here is what I have in my code

```
    it('should greet the named user', function () {
            // non angular site
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            browser.driver.get('http://example.com');
            browser.driver.findElement(By.id('post')).click();
            browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='go']")).click();
            browser.driver.findElement(By.css('.pickbutton')).click();
            browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='113']")).click();
            browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='3']")).click();


            //click login button //this works sometime but fails a lot..non-consistent
          browser.driver.findElement(By.id('loginBox')).findElements(By.tagName('p')).then(function (el) {
    el[2].click();

    });
  });
```

I have also tried different other things like below without any success.

```
1-     browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='button']")).click();
2-     browser.driver.findElement(By.id('loginBox a')).then(function (el) {
        el.click();
        });
```

Here is the stack

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was: 
WebElement.click()
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:302:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebElement.schedule_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1665:23)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebElement.click (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:1770:15)
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/testlist.js:64:27
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640:20)
    at notify (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:444:12)
    at notifyAll (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:422:7)
    at resolve (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:400:7)
F

Failures:

  1) Craigslist automation should greet the named user
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 10000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 10.855 seconds
1 test, 2 assertions, 1 failure
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: both solutions below worked for me. This also worked for me here
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/article/section/form/section/p[2]/input')).then(function (el) {
//                el.click();
//            });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the button with an xpath expression like this:

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() = 'Log In']")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  It might work out:-

`browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log In']")).submit();`